# Asp.net Script Manager Memory Leak

Tags: asp.net, memory, memory-leaks, scriptmanager

I am using asp.net script manager and the code is as given below:

```
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"  />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Core.js"  />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/TomasCore.js"  />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"  />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

When I run this application, the memory usage is creeping up by 5MB for every page refresh.

Could anyone please throw light on this??

Thanks,
Mahesh

Comment: Memory on the server or on the client?

Answer (score 1):

Chances are there is enough memory and the GC has no reason to kick in and free memory yet. You should test what happens if you loop like 200 calls.

Also can you reproduce this if you remove the ScriptManager?

Comment: If I remove the script manager, everything is fine. But in order to make my page ajaxed, I need script manager.

Comment: Oh it is IE that increases memory footprint not the web server?